# Reload the query after adding the record to mysql database with ajax without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a page where user can add the records to the mysql database. On the same page there is a list existing records in the database.

I use ajax to add the record to database, sorry for old version of mysql, will get updated after I get this thing to work first:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//on the click of the submit button 
$("#btn_submit").click(function(){
 //get the form values
 var username = $('#hdn_username').val();     
 var name = $('#txt_name').val();     
 var brand = $('#txt_brand').val(); 

 //make the postdata
 var postData = 'username='+username+'&name='+name+'&brand='+brand;

 //call your input.php script in the background, when it returns it will call the success function if the request was successful or the error one if there was an issue (like a 404, 500 or any other error status)

 $.ajax({
    url : "input.php",
    type: "POST",
    data : postData,
    success: function(data,status, xhr)
    {
        //if success then just output the text to the status div then clear the form inputs to prepare for new data
        $("#status_text").html(data);
        $('#name').val('');
        $('#brand').val('');
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown)
    {
        //if fail show error and server status
        $("#status_text").html('there was an error ' + errorThrown + ' with status ' + textStatus);
    }
});
}); });
```

My html is:

```
<table class="simplet" width="640" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width="300" colspan="2">Product Name</th>
<th width="150">Brand</th>
<th width="100">Quantity</th>
<th width="60">Price</th>
<th width="30">Delete</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td colspan="6"><div id="status_text_list" /></td></tr>

[insert_php]

$current_user= wp_get_current_user();
$username= $current_user->user_login;

mysql_connect("localhost","xxxxx","xxxx");//database connection
mysql_select_db("xxxx");

$query= "SELECT * FROM wp_userdata WHERE username='$username'";
$result= mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) { die("Error db request: <br />". mysql_error()); }

while ($result_row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){ echo '<tr class="odd-row"><td width="30"></td><td>'.$result_row['product_name'].'</td><td>'.$result_row['product_brand'].'</td><td>'.$result_row['product_quantity'].'</td><td>'.$result_row['product_link'].'</td><td><a class="link-delete" href="#" data-delete-id="' . $result_row['id'] . '">X</a></td></tr>';
}


[/insert_php]

</tbody></table>
<br />

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">Add Products</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
         <form onsubmit="return false">
      <table>
<input type="hidden" id="hdn_username" name="username" value="[insert_php]echo $username;[/insert_php]">
        <tr>
          <td>Product Name</td>
          <td><input type="text" id="txt_name" name="name" size="50">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Brand</td>
          <td><input type="text"  id="txt_brand" name="brand" size="50">
          </td>
        </tr>
<tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><div id="status_text" /></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td align="right"><input type="submit" id="btn_submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
</form>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And my input.php is:

```
mysql_connect("localhost","xxxx","xxxx");//database connection
mysql_select_db("xxxx");




//inserting data order
$order = "INSERT INTO wp_userdata
            (username, product_name, product_brand)
            VALUES
            ('$_POST[username]',
             '$_POST[name]',
            '$_POST[brand]')";

//declare in the order variable
$result = mysql_query($order);  //order executes
if($result){
    echo ("DATA SAVED SUCCESSFULLY");
} else{
    echo("<br>Input data is fail");
}
```

When I click the Submit button, form values sent to input.php and the success message is displayed, you can see it here -  http://suppliesprices.com/?page_id=4

What I want to achieve is to add the new data row to the displayed list without reloading the page.

I was thinking to render it with javascript and add to a success ajax call, but not sure if it going to work.

How do I change my code to get the desired effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add another row to the table, you can use the [jQuery append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function. You can do this inside you success function like so:

```
success: function(data,status, xhr)
{
    //if success then just output the text to the status div then clear the form inputs to prepare for new data
    if (data.status == 'success') {
        $("#status_text").html('DATA SAVED SUCCESSFULLY');
        $('#name').val('');
        $('#brand').val('');

        $('.simplet tbody').append('<tr class="odd-row"><td width="30"></td><td>'+data.product.product_name+'</td><td>'+data.product.product_brand+'</td><td>'+data.product.product_quantity+'</td><td>'+data.product.product_link+'</td><td><a class="link-delete" href="#" data-delete-id="' + data.product.id + '">X</a></td></tr>');
    } else {
        $("#status_text").html(data.message);
    }
},
```

You will want to update your PHP code to return some more information. Most commonly you would return JSON containing information about whether the transaction succeeded and a copy of the information that was inserted into your database (or an error message if it failed). You could do something like the following:

```
if($result){
    $id = mysql_insert_id();
    $retVal = array(
        'status' => 'success',
        'product' => array(
            'id' => $id,
            'product_name' => $_POST['name'],
            'product_brand' => $_POST['brand'],
            'product_quantity' => 0,
            'product_link' => '/?product_id=' . $id // not sure if this is the correct format or not 
        )
    );
} else {
    $retVal = array(
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => 'Product could not be inserted'
    );
}

header('Content-Type: text/json');
echo json_encode($retVal);
```

You definitely should update the database code to follow better security practices, but this should get you started.

Comment: when I apply the code< I was getting some mysql errors

Comment: Oops, shouldn't be passing $result into mysql_insert_id(). I edited it. Give that a try.

Comment: I get `{"status":"success","product":{"id":96,"product_name":"sdf","product_brand":"ffff","product_quantity":0,"product_link":"\/?product_id=96"}}` displayed in my `div id="status_text_list"`, and now row added to the table

Comment: Take a look at the edit now. I never updated your code from above. Feel free to pass whatever you want into the status DIV on success and failure. The above is just an example of how you could do it.

Comment: You are missing the if statement and didn't change the line below it. Make sure you have the line starting with "if". And make sure to update the line below it to match the one above.

Comment: I applied the changes but for some reason nothing happens http://suppliesprices.com/?page_id=4

Comment: Change the last 2 lines in your PHP file to match the edit above. The correct content type for JSON is actually application/json, but it won't work in older versions of IE. text/json should work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can do.

Option 1:

Just use a regular button `type='button'` rather than a submit button `type='submit'`.  A submit button by default changes the page, while a regular button does not.

Option 2:

```
$("#btn_submit").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
 //get the form values
```

See docs for [event.preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/). The default action of a submit button is to submit by going to the page defined in the form's `action` attribute (or back to the same page if you didn't specify an `action` attribute). This call prevents that default action so you can use Ajax instead.

And on the form, you can get rid of the `onsubmit="return false"` because that will not work.

Edit:

A bug I found in your Ajax.  You're using GET syntax with POST.

Do not use: `var postData = 'username='+username+'&name='+name+'&brand='+brand;` followed by `data : postData,` in your Ajax with POST.

Rather, use in your ajax `data: { username: username, name: name, brand: brand }`.  With POST the `=` and `&` are not used.

Also, in PHP: `$_POST[username]` is wrong.  Should be `$_POST['username']`.

Comment: i tried the second approach but doesnt work, here - http://suppliesprices.com/?page_id=4

Comment: And the result is what? With the first solution, if it fails, you definitely should not change pages nor refresh this page. It just won't do anything and you'll have to figure out where else you have a bug in your code.

Comment: I've changed the ajax part still no luck http://suppliesprices.com/?page_id=4 , php works fine without "'" when I add it it breaks